# Core Data multi context importing and faulting

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a a main `NSManagedObjectContext` used in a few UIViewControllers to display the data (which is a `UITableView` with a list of `Department`)

3 entities one `Department` with a to-one to `Boss` with a to-many to `Employee` (In this case the `employee` have an `NSData` (which is an image) attribute with `allow external storage`).

Since I'm importing images in batches I'm doing it in a background thread which has its own `NSManagedObjectContext`.

The importing consists in creating the `Boss` entity and all the `Employee` and setting up the relationships.

Now my issue is :

- if I use a `child context` of the `main context` for importing and save, then all the images stay in memory even though both context don't have changes.
- if I use a `context with no relation to the main context` the image aren't staying in memory but the new data isn't showed in the `UIViewController` (obviously since the `main context` isn't notified of the changes done by the `background context`)

So I would like to still have the changes appear without having the images in memory (meaning I would like the `Department` to know that it has a `Boss` relationship but without having the images in memory). In short I would like them to be turned into fault as soon as the `context` is saved.

EDIT : I think the problem is when I save the `child context`, it merges with the `main context` and from there the newly inserted images stay in memory :/ and I have no idea how to release them (and no they're not auto released even with memory warning...)

EDIT 2 : I think I fixed it, here's what I did :

- I used a `child context` tied to the `main context` and I listened to all the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and for all the `inserted` `updated` I call `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` on it to turn it into fault.

I registered for all the notifications from every context.

```
-(void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification*)saveNotification {
    NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext = saveNotification.object;
    NSArray *insertedObjects = [saveNotification.userInfo valueForKey:@"inserted"];
    if (insertedObject) {
        NSLog(@"INSERTED : %@", insertedObjects);
        for (NSManagedObject *object in insertedObjects) {
            [defaultContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];
        }
    }
    NSArray *updatedObjects = [saveNotification.userInfo valueForKey:@"updated"];
    if (insertedObject) {
        NSLog(@"UPDATED : %@", updatedObjects);
        for (NSManagedObject *object in updatedObjects) {
            [defaultContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like premature optimisation; the MOC should decide when to fault things for you. Are you actually having a problem caused by this, or do you just think it ought to work in a certain way?

Comment: Yes I am after 5-7 batch import (about 28Mb of images data /import) the app crashes, because the images are never faulted back.

Comment: Seems a bit messy having to have the notifications - the child context is supposed to solve that for you. Can't you call refreshObject on the child context, after you've finished adding and saving each one?

Comment: I tried but I think the objects are still living in the parent context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn a specific object into a fault using `refreshObject:mergeChanges:`, passing NO for the mergeChanges argument.

> Turning object into a fault (flag is NO) means that strong references to related managed objects (that is, those to which object has a reference) are broken, so you can also use this method to trim a portion of your object graph you want to constrain memory usage.

[Documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/refreshObject%3amergeChanges%3a).

Comment: Yeah I know that I read it like everywhere this seems to be the only way but I tried calling it and it doesn't seem to work in this case (it works when I call it on the main context but not the child) Also I read all the core data documentation I could find :/

Comment: Okay so I think I found a way to do what I wanted I'm gonna mark your answer as valid but before that could you tell me what you think about the way I solved it ? If it seems decent :/ ?

Comment: If you solved it yourself, you should answer your own question, and accept that answer, rather than edit the question.