# Core Data: NSObjectID and NSTemporaryObjectID leaks

Tags: core-data, memory-leaks, instruments, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Before I send my app to the App Store I like to check it for memory leaks and other fishy stuff with instruments. There is one Core Data issue that I can't seem to solve, so I've decided to create a small test app to illustrate the problem.

**What's the problem?**

When I save an entity in a (child) NSManagedObjectContext it is propagated to its parent NSManagedObjectContext. During this process Core Data creates internal instances of `_NSObjectID` and `NSTemporaryObjectID`. For some reason these instances are left behind and the only way to get rid of them is to reset the parent NSManagedObjectContext.

My app is of course a lot more complex than this little test app and resetting the NSManagedObjectContext isn't an option for me.

**Test app**

The test app is a standard iOS app based on the single view template with the CoreData option checked. I've used objective-c to keep it similar to my production app.

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Initialize the Core Data stack
    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    // Create the a private context
    self.rootContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.rootContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;

    // Create a child context
    self.childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.childContext.parentContext = self.rootContext;

    // Create a person
    [self.childContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        Person *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.childContext];
        person.name = @"John Smith";
        person.age = 30;

        // Save the person
        [self.childContext save:nil];

        // Save the root context
        [self.rootContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            [self.rootContext save:nil];
        }];
    }];

    return YES;
}
```

When you run the code above with instruments and the allocations instrument you can see that Core Data leaves some stuff behind.

You can find the full project here: https://github.com/Zyphrax/CoreDataLeak

[image: Instruments]

**Things I've tried**

I've tried things like `[context refreshObject:... mergeChanges:YES]`,  adding `@autoreleasepool` and/or `[context processPendingChanges]` inside the blocks, it all doesn't help. The only way to get it clean is to do a `[context reset]` (sledgehammer approach).

It's hard to find other people reporting this problem.
This blog post seems similar:
http://finalize.com/2013/01/04/core-data-issues-with-memory-allocation/

I hope you guys can help me with this.

Comment: Downloaded project, ran it in instruments, and it did not see anything show up in leaks.  XCode 6.4, deployment target 8.4, iPhone 6 simulator.  I'd be willing to look, if you can provide something else to go on.

Comment: Jody thanks for looking into this. You should be able to reproduce it with these steps: (1) Open the project in Xcode 6.4, (2) Profile for allocations/leaks with the iPad 2 / iOS 8,4 simulator, (3) The leaks instrument won't detect any leaks, but when you filter on NSTemporaryObjectID or _NSObjectID you should see persistent instances that should have been deallocated (similar to the screenshot above, for the screenshot I used the Xcode 7 profiler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I see, which is very similar to yours...

[image]

However, I don't know that I would be concerned, unless you see lots of these, and they never go away.  I assume the internals of Core Data (including the row cache has) some sort of object caching going on.

On the other hand, my Core Data usage has changed a bit over the past year or two.

Unless it is a very simple app, I almost never create new objects in a child context.  I will fetch and modify them, but if I end up creating a new object, I make sure that is done in a sibling context.

However, if you modify your code slightly, by adding this line (with your appropriate error handling - it returns `BOOL`) before the initial save...

```
NSArray *inserted = self.childContext.insertedObjects.allObjects;
[self.childContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:inserted error:&error];
```

you should get something like this instruments report, which shows all objects created as being transient...

[image]

Thus, I don't necessarily think it is a permanent leak, because once I force the context to convert to a permanent ID, the objects go away.  However, who knows how long they keep those object ID objects cached.

In general, when I create objects in a context that contains a hierarchy, I will always obtain permanent IDs first (for many reasons).  However, as I said earlier, I usually create new objects in a context that is directly created to the persistent store (because I have had to deal with other issues related to hierarchies temporary object IDs, especially when using multiple non related contexts).

Comment: Hi Jody, thanks for your answer! I'll try the obtainPermanentIDsForObject method. If you create a context that is directly connected to the persistent store, how do you notify other contexts of changes done in your context?

Comment: Core Data will automatically send `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` to the default notification center anytime a context is saved.  Likewise, `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` will be sent anytime a change is made to a context.  Lots of questions on SO and lots of information elsewhere on how to do this.  If you find yourself stumped, post another question - hit me with a comment directing me and I'll take a look.